# Why is my transform scale not working with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm a total beginner to this. I'm just learning bootstrap and I realized that the animation breaks if I apply it (only the scaling bit). It works just fine without Bootstrap. Is there any other alternative?

HTML

```
    <main class="row g-0 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 g-0 ">
            <div class="left_side text-center ">
                <h1 class="titulo_index">¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
                <p class="texto_index">Desde 1933 tostamos nuestro propio café.
            Lo cuidamos desde la selección de sus granos, hasta la taza, conservando el amor y el respeto que tenemos por lo que hacemos, desde el primer día. Por eso nuestro café es <strong> ÚNICO.</strong>
                </p>
                <a id="i_link" class="index_link" href="menu.html">¡Conoce nuestro menu!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
.index_link{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    width: 400px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #d99771;
    border: #442b0c 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px black;
}
.index_link:hover{
    background-color: #dbb098;
    scale: 1.2;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the `a` has `display: inline;`.
You can just add `.d-block` or `.d-inline-block` to have the scale applied.

```html
<a id="i_link" class="index_link d-inline-block" href="menu.html">¡Conoce nuestro menu!</a>
```

```css
.index_link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 400px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #d99771;
  border: #442b0c 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px black;
}

.index_link:hover {
  background-color: #dbb098;
  scale: 1.2;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">


<main class="row g-0 align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-6 g-0 ">
    <div class="left_side text-center ">
      <h1 class="titulo_index">¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
      <p class="texto_index">Desde 1933 tostamos nuestro propio café. Lo cuidamos desde la selección de sus granos, hasta la taza, conservando el amor y el respeto que tenemos por lo que hacemos, desde el primer día. Por eso nuestro café es <strong> ÚNICO.</strong>
      </p>
      <a id="i_link" class="index_link d-inline-block" href="menu.html">¡Conoce nuestro menu!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can set the `display` in your CSS.

```css
.index_link {
  
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```css
.index_link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 400px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #d99771;
  border: #442b0c 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px black;
}

.index_link:hover {
  background-color: #dbb098;
  scale: 1.2;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">


<main class="row g-0 align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-6 g-0 ">
    <div class="left_side text-center ">
      <h1 class="titulo_index">¿Quienes Somos?</h1>
      <p class="texto_index">Desde 1933 tostamos nuestro propio café. Lo cuidamos desde la selección de sus granos, hasta la taza, conservando el amor y el respeto que tenemos por lo que hacemos, desde el primer día. Por eso nuestro café es <strong> ÚNICO.</strong>
      </p>
      <a id="i_link" class="index_link" href="menu.html">¡Conoce nuestro menu!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```